# Codeigniter 3 - encryption create same string with ctr mode

Tags: php, codeigniter, encryption, codeigniter-3

I am using CI3 encryption library. Is it possible to create same encrypted string every time, using **ctr** mode, or I have to use less secure **ecb**. This are my settings:

```
$this->encryption->initialize(
            [
                'cipher' => 'aes-256',
                'mode'   => 'ctr',
                'key'    => 'xxx'
            ]

        );
```

Inserting serials:

```
public function insertSerials($serials, $type)
    {
        $data = [];

        $now = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

        foreach ($serials as $serial):
            $data[] = [
                'serial'     => $this->encryption->encrypt($serial),
                'type'       => $type,
                'date_added' => $now,
            ];
        endforeach;

        $this->db->insert_batch($this->_table_name, $data);
    }
```

Comment: I need to insert unique code in the db. If the code exist, the record shouldn't be inserted and error is thrown.

Comment: I have a list of keys which needs to be inserted in db encrypted. Every key inserted in the db needs to be unique. At the moment I can use same file as many times as I want, thus creating new records every time - same keys are in the db multiple times. I am trying to avoid this.

Comment: I added code which is inserting data into db.

Comment: "I need to insert unique code in the db." Encryption is *not* the correct tool for the job here. Related: https://paragonie.com/blog/2015/09/comprehensive-guide-url-parameter-encryption-in-php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All modes except the ECB mode require some kind of Initialization Vector. For CTR this is called a nonce. It is crucial for CTR mode to have unique IV on every encryption with the same key, because otherwise it would be easy to recover many of the plaintexts with some clever deductions. Using a static nonce for CTR would have more devastating results than using ECB.

It seems you actually want to give up semantic security, so there is nothing wrong with using ECB mode. A CBC mode with a static IV would have been better, but that's not possible in [CI3](https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/blob/3.0.3/system/libraries/Encryption.php#L460-L470).

Comment: I see. Thanks for the explanation :)

Comment: @Sasha By the way, I answered only your immediate question without mentioning whether this makes sense or not. You haven't clearly explained why you want to have "unique" values in the database or what you want to do with those values. I suggest that you think about the alternatives such as generating random tokens or using hashing (or even hashids).

Comment: @Scott I must have seen such a picture on Wikipedia, but I could find it anymore. It was multiple black and white images, one with a circle and the other with a square, then they were encrypted and the resulting ciphertexts were XORed to reveal the shapes of the initial images. I would very much like to have this example in my library, but I would want to impose on you that you create those from scratch.

Comment: I finally found one variant of the [CTR penguin](https://twitter.com/angealbertini/status/425561082841690112/photo/1) which shows how horribly CTR mode breaks when you would reuse a nonce (deterministic).